# how to show a food menu items in heading wise

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have two table:

```
SELECT *
INTO #tblVariety 
FROM (VALUES
('DT001', 'Veg',     '2016-09-30'),
('DT002', 'Non-Veg', '2016-09-30'),
('DT003', 'Coffee',  '2016-09-30'),
('DT004', 'Cakes',   '2016-09-30')
) as t(DID, Dishtype, AddedDate)

SELECT *
INTO #tblProducts 
FROM (VALUES
('MN001',   'Dosa',                 'South indian famous food',                     60,     'Veg'),
('MN002',   'Meals',                'Rice and chenna fry and more indian culture',  150,    'Veg'),
('MN003',   'Burger',               'Its chines made culture and fastfoods',        80,     'Veg'),
('MN004',   'Chettinadu chicken',   'Its very tasty and spicy',                     100,    'Non-Veg'),
('MN005',   'chicken Loipop',       'this chicken leg piece fry',                   120,    'Non-Veg'),
('MN006',   'Grill chicken',        'its very fry in grill machines',               350,    'Non-Veg'),
('MN007',   'choco cofee',          'its hard choco and sweetest without milk',     100,    'Coffee'),
('MN008',   'Mintmojiti',           'mint tast its feel fresh',                     100,    'Coffee'),
('MN009',   'Straberry Milkshake',  'Its healthy and sweetest items',               150,    'Coffee'),
('MN010',   'Home Strawberry',      'its a sweetest and tasty',                     90,     'Coffee'),
('MN011',   'Chocolate cake',       'its a dark choco and soft emmy',               300,    'Cakes'),
('MN012',   'Mary Berry',           'its formal and crunchi cake',                  200,    'Cakes'),
('MN013',   'Buttar',               'confetti its a milk mixed made cake',          150,    'Cakes')
) as t(ProId, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice, VNV)
```

I want output in:

```
                                                          Veg

 Dosa                                                    Meals                                                                     Burger
 South indian famous food                Rice and chenna fry and more indian culture     cheinese ffood
 60                                                             150                                                                  80


                                                          Non-Veg

Chettinadu chicken
 Its very tasty and spicy
100 

                                                          Cofee


 (values)...................................


                                                          Cakes
(Values).............................................
```

Any one please help me

Comment: Please format the Question text, I might not be able to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use pivoting:

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT  ProId, 
                VNV as Dishtype,
                CAST(VNV as nvarchar(max)) as Product,
                CAST(ProductName as nvarchar(max)) as ProductName, 
                CAST(ProductDescription as nvarchar(max)) as ProductDescription, 
                CAST(ProductPrice as nvarchar(max)) as ProductPrice, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VNV ORDER BY ProId) as seq
        FROM #tblProducts 
    ) as m
    UNPIVOT (
        [Values] FOR [Columns] IN (Product, ProductName, ProductDescription, ProductPrice)
    ) as unpvt
) as d
)

SELECT  c.[Values],
        c1.[Values],
        c2.[Values]
FROM cte c
LEFT JOIN cte c1 
    ON c.[Columns] = c1.[Columns] and c1.seq = c.seq+1 AND c.Dishtype=c1.Dishtype
LEFT JOIN cte c2
    ON c1.[Columns] = c2.[Columns] and c2.seq = c1.seq+1 AND c1.Dishtype=c2.Dishtype
WHERE c.seq IN (1,4,7,10)
```

Output:

```
Values                                     |Values                                     |Values
-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------
Cakes                                       Cakes                                       Cakes
Chocolate cake                              Mary Berry                                  Buttar
its a dark choco and soft emmy              its formal and crunchi cake confetti        its a milk mixed made cake
300                                         200                                         150
Coffee                                      Coffee                                      Coffee
choco cofee                                 Mintmojiti                                  Straberry Milkshake
its hard choco and sweetest without milk    mint tast its feel fresh                    Its healthy and sweetest items
100                                         100                                         150
Coffee                                      NULL                                        NULL
Home Strawberry                             NULL                                        NULL
its a sweetest and tasty                    NULL                                        NULL
90                                          NULL                                        NULL
Non-Veg                                     Non-Veg                                     Non-Veg
Chettinadu chicken                          chicken Loipop                              Grill chicken
Its very tasty and spicy                    this chicken leg piece fry                  its very fry in grill machines
100                                         120                                         350
Veg                                         Veg                                         Veg
Dosa                                        Meals                                       Burger
South indian famous food                    Rice and chenna fry and more indian culture Its chines made culture and fastfoods
60                                          150                                         80
```

Another way is to put all menu into XML and use XSLT or whatever to transform it into format you need:

```
SELECT  t.VNV '@type',
        CAST((
        SELECT  ProId '@prodid', 
                ProductName '@prodname', 
                ProductDescription '@proddesc', 
                ProductPrice '@prodprice'
        FROM #tblProducts
        WHERE t.VNV = VNV
        FOR XML PATH('dish')
        ) as xml) as proddetails
FROM #tblProducts t
GROUP BY t.VNV
FOR XML PATH('dish')
```

Output:

```
<dish type="Cakes">
  <proddetails>
    <dish prodid="MN011" prodname="Chocolate cake" proddesc="its a dark choco and soft emmy" prodprice="300" />
    <dish prodid="MN012" prodname="Mary Berry" proddesc="its formal and crunchi cake" prodprice="200" />
    <dish prodid="MN013" prodname="Buttar" proddesc="confetti its a milk mixed made cake" prodprice="150" />
  </proddetails>
</dish>
<dish type="Coffee">
  <proddetails>
    <dish prodid="MN007" prodname="choco cofee" proddesc="its hard choco and sweetest without milk" prodprice="100" />
    <dish prodid="MN008" prodname="Mintmojiti" proddesc="mint tast its feel fresh" prodprice="100" />
    <dish prodid="MN009" prodname="Straberry Milkshake" proddesc="Its healthy and sweetest items" prodprice="150" />
    <dish prodid="MN010" prodname="Home Strawberry" proddesc="its a sweetest and tasty" prodprice="90" />
  </proddetails>
</dish>
<dish type="Non-Veg">
  <proddetails>
    <dish prodid="MN004" prodname="Chettinadu chicken" proddesc="Its very tasty and spicy" prodprice="100" />
    <dish prodid="MN005" prodname="chicken Loipop" proddesc="this chicken leg piece fry" prodprice="120" />
    <dish prodid="MN006" prodname="Grill chicken" proddesc="its very fry in grill machines" prodprice="350" />
  </proddetails>
</dish>
<dish type="Veg">
  <proddetails>
    <dish prodid="MN001" prodname="Dosa" proddesc="South indian famous food" prodprice="60" />
    <dish prodid="MN002" prodname="Meals" proddesc="Rice and chenna fry and more indian culture" prodprice="150" />
    <dish prodid="MN003" prodname="Burger" proddesc="Its chines made culture and fastfoods" prodprice="80" />
  </proddetails>
</dish>
```